GNU Radio and gr-inspector
I have a problem in GNU Radio regarding the gr-inspector. I want to save the data it provides me (using a Python block) in a csv format. The actual problem is that I don't know what kind of data it has at the map_out port and what kind of input data should I make for the Python block in order to connect them.
[Those are my GNU Radio blocks]


Have you tryed to just save it as a text file with say 1000 rows and then inspect the output if you can not print it out?

I’m voting to close this question because it was verbatimly copied to ham.SE, and has more information there: https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/22680/gnu-radio-and-gr-inspector
